# ANTLR4 variable types and order of operations

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have two grammars:

Hello.g4:

```
grammar Hello;
start: exp? EOF;
exp: int_exp | vector_exp;
int_exp: int_exp '*' int_exp | int_exp '+' int_exp | INT;
vector_exp: vector_exp '*' int_exp | int_exp '*' vector_exp | 
            vector_exp '+' vector_exp | VECTOR;
INT  : ('0'..'9') | (('1'..'9')('0'..'9')+);
VECTOR: 'v';
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Hello2.g4

```
grammar Hello2;
start: exp? EOF;
exp: add;
add: add '+' add | mult '+' add | add '+' mult | mult;
mult: mult '*' mult | INT '*' mult | mult '*' INT | INT | VECTOR;
INT  : ('0'..'9') | (('1'..'9')('0'..'9')+);
VECTOR: 'v';
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The first grammar checks the types correctly: adding a vector to a scalar `v+1` doesnt work. But it fails to have the correct order of operations.

`1+1*v` gives

[image: wrong order]

The second grammar has the correct order, but allows `v+1`, which shouldnt work.

I understand *why* the grammars work like that, but I fail to combine these two, creating a grammar that checks types and has the correct order of operations.

Whatever I check first works, my problem is that I have to start somewhere breaking the thing that I do second. How would one combine these two requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not allowing to add a scalar to a vector is a semantic rule, not a syntactic one. A parser can only cover syntactic rules. You have to enforce semantic rules after parsing, e.g. in a visitor that walks the produced parse tree.

Comment: But what if my scalars are always numbers and my vectors are always strings, is it impossible or a bad idea?

Comment: How the semantic rules look like is up to you. That doesn't change the general idea: enforce them in a second step, after you've done with parsing.